# GraphQL subscriptions: Error on calling apolloClient.subscribe

Tags: graphql, subscription, graphql-js, graphql-subscriptions

I think I have the backend subscription setup correctly. I am using angular on the client side, when I try to call `subscribe` I got an error

```
passwordUpdatedSubscription = gql`
subscription passwordUpdated{passwordUpdated{name password}}
`;

// Apollo Subscription
var subscription = this.apollo.subscribe({
  query: this.passwordUpdatedSubscription
});

subscription.subscribe(
  {
    next(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error(err) { console.error('err', err); },
  }
);
```

And then this is the error appears in the console
`{"type":"subscription_fail","id":0,"payload":{"errors":[{"message":"Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"}]}}`

Maybe I am missing something on the backend? Do I need to define the `setupFunctions` in the `SubscriptionManager`?

This is my SubscriptionManager

```
const sub = require('graphql-subscriptions');
const pubSub = new sub.PubSub();
const manager = new sub.SubscriptionManager({
    schema,
    pubSub
});
```

This is my schema in graphQL

```
const graphql = require('graphql');

var schema = graphql.buildSchema(`
    type Subscription {
      passwordUpdated: User
    }
    type Mutation {
      setMessage(message: String): String,
      updateUserPassword(userName: String, password: String): User!
    }

    type Query {
      getMessage: String,
      getUsers: [User],
      findUsers(userName: String): [User]
    }

    type User {
        name: String,
        password: String
    }
`);
```

Comment: the error is telling you that the apollo client is undefined in this context. Did you already check that?

Comment: @Locco0_0, I have checked that. it was not undefined. The other operations such as `watchQuery` and `mutation` are working though

Comment: Good, so please show the Subscription Manager on the server. And which node packages do you use? And i guess you are missing the setup function. What kind of publish-subscription do you use?

Comment: @Locco0_0, updated my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are missing the setup function. You could take a look at this links [graphql subscription docu](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-subscriptions) or [example](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/graphql-subscriptions-in-apollo-client-9a2457f015fb#.9c53tqfib).

Your subscription manager could look like this:

```js
const manager = new sub.SubscriptionManager({
  schema,
  pubSub,

  setupFunctions: {
    passwordUpdated: (options, args) => ({ // name of your graphQL subscription
      passwordUpdatedChannel: { // name of your pubsub publish-tag
        filter: () => {
          return true
        },
      },
    }),
  },
});
```

When you call the pubsub publish function you have to write it like this `pubsub.publish("passwordUpdatedChannel")`.

Sidenode: You might want to add the id of the user that has the password changed to the subscription. If you do that you can add it to the filter option, could look like this `filter: (user) => {return user.id === args.userId}`

Comment: Thanks! It fixed the problem!